# Django: Run a function if certain condition is met

Tags: django, function, django-models

I have a Word model, where a user can add words and various fields, like this (shortened version):

```
class Word(models.Model):
    target_word = models.CharField()
    source_word = models.CharField()
    add_to_review = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    example_sentence = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/',blank=True)
```

I also have a Flashcard model where a user can add and study flashcards. Here I show only the relevant code:

```
class FlashcardManager(models.Manager):
    def create_flashcard(self, user, question, answer, deck_name):
        try:
            deck = Deck.objects.get(owner=user, name=deck_name)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            deck = Deck(owner=user, name=deck_name)
            deck.save()

        self.create(owner=user, question=question, answer=answer,
                    deck=deck)
        return deck

class Flashcard(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_shown_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    next_due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    difficulty = models.FloatField(default=2.5)
    consec_correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = FlashcardManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

When a user creates a new word, I want to give them the option of automatically creating a flashcard using the info provided. In other words, question = target_word, answer = source_word, and the deck name can either be some default value, or I can add a field to the Word model. Is there a way I can do this by using the add_to_review field of the Word model and the create_flashcard method of the FlashcardManager model? I've tried adding a function to my Word model that runs if add_to_review is true. I don't get any errors, but nothing happens.

I know one option would be to just combine the two models... but I do have my own reasons for keeping them seperate. I might still do that, but I was just wondering if what I am trying to do is possible / feasible? I'm not really sure what exactly to google, so haven't been able to find any info on this. So any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can use signals such as `post_save` or `post_delete` on your `Word` model.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/

Comment: @Uri Are you able to provide an example in an answer? I tried using the signals, but it's not working (the signal is not being called). Not sure what I'm doing wrong - should I post a new question?

Comment: @Uri Never mind, I figured it out :)

Comment: Update your question and write what you tried and not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it worked. Initially I had problems with the signal not being called, but this got fixed when I moved it to my models.py file instead of having it separate in a signals.py file.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Word)
def flash_from_word(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        flash_wanted = Word.objects.filter(add_to_review=True)
        instance._meta.model.objects.all()
        target_word = instance.target_word
        source_word = instance.source_word
        deck_name = instance.deck_name
        user = instance.user
        if flash_wanted:
            flash = Flashcard.objects.create(owner=user, question=target_word,answer=source_word,deck=Deck.objects.get(name=deck_name,owner=user))

post_save.connect(flash_from_word, sender=Word)
```